# Connecting to sybase using jdbc in solaris

Tags: java, jdbc, solaris, sybase, jconnect

I am trying to learn how to use jdbc.
Normally to connect to sybase db on solaris I use:

```
isql -Usa -Pxxxxxx -Dxxxxxx
```

its gets connected to the db by the above.and i can rightaway execute the queries.

Now i am trying to just do a similar thing using java.

below is my code.

```
public class SKRSample
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try
      {
        Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver");
      }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
      {
      System.err.println("Error loading driver: " + cnfe);
      }
    try
      {
       String host = "172.16.65.33";
       String dbName = "bsmdb";
       int port = 1234;
       String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:" + host + ":" + port + ":" + "?SERVICENAME=" + dbName;

        for (int n = 0; n<args.length; n++) {
         if (args[n].equals("-u")) user = args[++n];
         else if (args[n].equals("-p")) password = args[++n];
         else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown argument.");
        }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);//here is the error.
```

The last line of the code is where there is a runtime error.

i compiled the code and execueted as below:

```
setenv LOGIN "sa"
setenv PASSWORD "xxxxxxx"
javac SKRSample.java
java SKRSample -u $LOGIN -p $PASSWORD
```

the error i am getting is :

```
Unexpected exception : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sybase:Tds:172.16.65.33:1234:?SERVICENAME=bsmdb, sqlstate = 08001
```

i have a doubt that either the host is incorrect or the port is incorrect or the url i am framing is incorrect.how can get the host name if at all it is incorrect.and also how can get the port number if the problem lies there.
But i am not sure about the problem.Can anyone give me some head's up regarding where exactly the problem is there.

Comment: Is this [tag:sybase-asa], [tag:sybase-ase], [tag:sybase-iq], or [tag:sqlanywhere]? Trying to clean up the [tag:sybase] tag...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the JDBC url format is wrong.
the right format is `jdbc:jtds:sybase://<host>[:<port>][/<database_name>]`

Comment: post the Exception trace please

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper JDBC driver and connection string together. For example, you can use "com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver" (in jconn2.jar) and "jdbc:sybase:Tds:MyDbComputerNameOrIP:2638" together. Please check the following page for more options.

[Sybase JDBC Driver and URL Information](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/help_sybase.html)

In your code, it seems that you added extra ":" in the connection URL. Remote the ":" after port number. The following two connection URL should work with "com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver".

```
String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:" + host + ":" + port + "?SERVICENAME=" + dbName;
```

or

```
String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
```

Comment: What's the exception and what's your driver version? jConnect7?

Comment: the trace is :
Error loading driver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver
Any of the following may throw an SQLException.
Opening a connection.

Comment: Can you find that class in your jdbc driver JAR? Or use other version, for example, jdbc3/jdbc4. Can you try com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver with the connection URL I post above?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download the driver and execute the class so that it uses the driver in the path specified by you.

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

And use JTDS driver jar in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late, but still I had the same issue and spent much time investigating, so I'll put some outcome here:

1. We need to include the driver class in our code as well as java.sql:
    **import com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver;

    import java.sql.*;**

 2. We need to run javac with the path to the driver in the classpath (I have jconn3.jar here - /usr/local/localagent/jar/jconn3.jar):
**javac -cp "/usr/local/localagent/jar/*" test_conn.java**

 3. We need to put the same classpath when running the class:
**java -cp ".:/usr/local/localagent/jar/*" test_conn**

My code for test_conn.java is below:

```
    import com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver;
    import java.sql.*;

    public class test_conn {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String host = "myhost";
            String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:"+host+":4100";
            String username = "username";
            String password ="password";
            String dbname ="dbname";
            SybDriver sybDriver = null;
            Connection conn;

            try 
            {
                sybDriver=(SybDriver)Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
                System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sybase:Tds:"+host+":4100?SERVICENAME="+dbname, username, password);

                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("sp_helpdb");
                rs.next();
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                conn.close();

            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

It worked for me, so I hope this helps.